# Cannot find module 'semver' when install vue-cli

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Error: Cannot find module 'semver' when install vue-js

OS: Windows 7

node version: v6.17

i uninstalled v6.17 and install 8.3 but not worked..how can i solve?

Comment: You probably need to reinstall Node and or NPM, possibly manually removing the directories if you get an error with `npm install npm -g`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> npm install --save -g semver

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to fix the problem deleting files and reinstalling again. this works fine for me.

First, remove old staff**

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* ~/.npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo apt autoremove
```

**and then install again with the command:**

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```